# Call app needs long time to start

Tags: calls, samsung-galaxy-ace

The call app on my Samsung Galaxy Ace takes a really long time to start (about 20 seconds). When it finally starts and I cancel the call and call again, the app launches normally. When I turn off the screen and turn it on again, the app starts again delayed. I was watching the LogCat output, and it gives me this:

```
07-21 21:11:08.710: D/PowerManagerService(1502): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=ActivityManager-Launch
07-21 21:11:11.390: D/BatteryService(1502): update start
07-21 21:11:14.703: W/PowerManagerService(1502): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
07-21 21:11:21.421: D/BatteryService(1502): update start
07-21 21:11:22.531: W/ActivityManager(1502): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{407bdff8 android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF} - receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@40bd2f18, started 20000ms ago
07-21 21:11:22.531: W/ActivityManager(1502): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{40bf3618 ReceiverList{40bd2f88 23024 com.google.android.youtube/10057 remote:40bd2f18}}
07-21 21:11:22.554: I/Launcher(19091): ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
07-21 21:11:22.578: D/PowerManagerService(1502): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=GeofencerStateMachine
07-21 21:11:22.578: D/PowerManagerService(1502): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=GeofencerStateMachine
I think it has something to do with this line:

07-21 21:11:22.531: W/ActivityManager(1502): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{407bdff8 android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF} - receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@40bd2f18, started 20000ms ago
```

but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What is the call app? Have you checked on Play store for updates? Emailed the developer in question?

Comment: I think he is talking about the default dialer app.

Comment: Re-reading the output of logcat, it's showing youtube is mis-behaving (Look at BinderProxy's address corresponds to `com.google.android.youtube/10057 remote:40bd2f18`) has nothing to do with call app... just saying

Comment: It is the default call app. 
I don't know how to find updates for that...

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue on my Galaxy S2(Android version 2.3.5). It was cause by Youtube, not the call app. When I saw the log related to youtube, I tried to start youtube by touching its icon, but it failed to start. You can try to see if you can start youtube now.

Then I went to "Settings/Application/Manage Applications" and found "Youtube". Cleared its data and cache. Now try to start youtube again. If it cannot start, check if you has disabled data sync. Enable it in "Settings/Account and Sync/Background data". Try to sync your data to allow youtube to update. After youtube is updated, it should be ok for the call app to work properly.

Hope this can also fix your problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about cache memory.

Whenever you load any application, it will be loaded in cache memory first and then Android will load that app on your screen from that cache.

If the call app was recently used, it might be stored in cache still, and thus it will load on your screen quickly.

Once you go out or lock the screen, cache memory will be cleared and when you start the call app, Android will have to load it again in cache memory as it is the first time. It will take some time to appear on screen afterwards because of this.

The trick to this situation not to kill the call app if you use it very often. Just leave it in your recent app list or background apps.